# How can I use the "signature" function in Preview on Mac Mini with no camera?

Tags: mac, pdf, preview

I have a Mac Mini with no attached camera. I would like to use the feature of Preview that allows you to insert a signature. This relies on taking an image of your signature using an isight/facetime/webcam. I do not have on.

I do have a MacBook pro on which I use the signature function. Is there a way to copy a file from the the MacBook Pro to the Mac Mini to enable this function on the Mini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently can transfer the signature from your Macbook to your Mac Mini. This webpage explains the process:

http://www.stuartcarnie.com/2011/08/transferring-preview-app-signatures-in.html

Hope it helps! If you run into any problems feel free to ask.